# Firebase callable function in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

Is Firebase callable function supported for use with react native?

I deployed an onCall function and I can see it in my dashboard

I also initalized functions using

```
 // Initialize Cloud Functions through Firebase
 firebase.functions();
```

And im calling the function using

```
    const func = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('funcName');

    func({
        param1: '',
        param2: '',
        param3: '',
        param4: ''
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('success')
        console.log(res)
    })
```

But every time i make the call the promise is rejected with message 'not-found'

my firebase version is 7.6.1

function code:

```
  export const funcName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => 
     {
  return { message: 'success' }
   })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show both the client and function code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem i was having was coming from my firebase config

```
 {
  apiKey: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  storageBucket: ""
 }
```

Once i updated it this it worked

```
{

    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
}
```

Comment: If you were able to solve your issue, please consider accepting your own answer :)